# How can i automate server health check without using selenium

Tags: java, automation

I want to automate a server health check that is configured using weblogic. I have to login to weblogic console to view server's health. If I think about automating this process, then the only way known to me is selenium. But i dont want to use it. Is there any other way through which i can login to weblogic console and get the health status of server in java

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pretty simple: if you don't have components at hand that provide you the functionality you are looking for; then you will have to see what it takes to implement it by yourself.

You could start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/monitoring.html) for example. Or for a slightly different approach [there](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2011/03/16/weblogic-server-runtime-using-wlst/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the API automation, instead of UI automation. You have to find out if there are any API exposed to get the data. If there are APIs available then you can use httpClient library in java for API automation.

Comment: How i am supposed to get which API will be called by weblogic console when i try to login

Comment: I checked, there are no web services exposed for this. But you can obtain server health programmatically , check this link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/monitoring.html#1034926   and for the precise code check this link http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2851